# php oop and jquery

Tags: php, jquery, oop

I am new to PHP-OOP and am wondering whether there is anything wrong with the way I code. I hope I don't get a decrease in reputation for asking for better coding ways. I have an index.php, product.php, see_category.php.

Below is my product.php:

[image]
[image]

Next this is my index.php:

[image]

Lastly this is my see_category.php

[image]

My question is, is this the correct way to do it? Are there better way's to do it?

Comment: I would remove inline JavaScript and find a way to send information to functions that are not obtrusive. http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/unobtrusive-javascript/

Comment: Looks okay, better than a lot of other code I've see over time. I would like to point you to the [Pear Coding Standards page](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.php). Not 100% necessary by any stretch, but it's what I always insist on in any team or work involving PHP because it's a nice standard in my personal opinion.

Comment: You should do something to validate/cleanse this: `$category = $_POST['category'];`. If "category" key does not exist in the array, then your script will blow up. Also, should validate that it is what you are expecting. I have a utility function that basically does the following: `$category = Core::getArrayValue("category", $_POST, "defaultCategory");` so that if it doesn't exist, it will simply return the default value.

Comment: +1 for using Netbeans :D

Comment: Why did you take pictures of the code, and not just copy and paste it?

Answer (score 3):

Looks fine, just some points you might wanna investigate:
What you are doing is commonly called AHAH, as opposed to AJAX (loading html from the server).
Post is usually used to make changes, create products, update products etc. you should stick to GET for the rest.
jquery has a very simple way of performing AHAH (this also removes the inline js):

```
$('#computers').on('click', function() {
    $(this).load('see_category.php?cat=computers');
});
```

You might wanna look up JSON, so that you can move away from rendering on the server side, and serve objects to the client, and render them through javascript.

Comment: I can't get it to work, but never mind, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is the wrong place for this kind of question, you'll want to be over at [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). However; my opinion is that the `see_category.php` file should be something like `product_controller.php` and it should serve as a controller for all product related functions. You should be checking for the existence of the post variable and acting accordingly based on what's in the post variable.

```
require_once('product.php');
$product = new Product();
```

The server will only be inside of this file if there's a request for a post, no reason not to instantiate the class regardless of the post condition.

```
if($_POST): 
    switch($_POST):
        case 'category' : 
           echo $product->set_products_by_category($_POST['category'], TRUE);
           break;
    endswitch; 
endif;
```

You'll notice in the above I'm not generating a table, I'm just echoing what's returned, but I added a 2nd argument and passed in the TRUE value, let's take a look at our function now.

```
public function set_products_by_category($category, $echo = FALSE){
   //your current code
   //after the while statement...
   if(TRUE === $echo):
       return $this->generate_table();
   endif;
}
```

Because we passed in true as the 2nd argument, it will automatically return the table to us, and we'll echo it out based on our `case` condition.

Comment: I've changed the file name as suggested by you and included if($_POST).

Answer (score 1):

**MySQL Injection**
You are doing this, and not escaping mysql characters. So it would be easy to inject code.

```
"SELECT * FROM product WHERE product_category='" . $category . "'"
```

The above code I could do a POST, where the $category can contain an injection. Please do a [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

**Javascript**
Provide Javascript in a different file so it is better for your SEO and your website structure. Currently your `jquery.js` is in the root directory. If you create a subdirectory for your Javascript files. You got more overview of your project files.

**Num rows**
You are counting yourself, why not use `$sth->num_rows`?

**Product class**
Seems like your `Product` is not actually a product. It is more a group holder. Maybe call it ProductOverview or something more relevant.

**Model View Controller**
Currently your product class does everything. Maybe look more into a [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) way of building your webpages. Maybe use [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) Template to keep your HTML seperated. Or a different Template Engine.

**OOP**
You wan't to be more Object orientated but your using `FETCH_ASSOC` which returns an Array not an Object. Why not using `FETCH_OBJECT`?

**Get products**
You are using 2 functions with almost the same result. It might be better to put up an optional parameter where you use 1 function instead of 2.

Comment: Thanks I made a couple of changes as your advice. Since mysql_real_escape_string will be deprecated soon, I use, 

$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM product");
$sth->execute();

What do you think?

Comment: As long as it's prevented mysql injection you should be fine!

Comment: Take a look at PDO if you want to be more object-oriented :)